# getting Invariant Violation error when using <List> and <FlatList> in react-native on android

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

i'm using to render some contents as a list, in react-native using  and . here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { Card, List, ListItem, Button, Icon, Image } from 'react-native-elements';
import { fb, database } from '../../../config/config';

export default class Vehicles extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      v_number: '',
      v_brand: '',
      v_type: '',
      user: null,
      v_list: []
    };
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.vehicleContainer}>
        <Button
          title=" Logout"
        />
        {
          this.state.v_list != null ? (
            <List>
              <FlatList
                data={this.state.v_list}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <ListItem
                    roundAvatar
                    title={item.details.vehicle_number}
                    subtitle={item.details.vehicle_type}
                    leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg' } }}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </List>
          ) : (
            <Text>Empty</Text>
          )
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  vehicleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  },
  ti1: {
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 300,
    height: 40
  }
});
```

i'm getting two error after executing this code. first one is,

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,
 You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

second error is,

```
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

when i use  and , it is working. but when i use  and , i'm getting those errors.
how can i fix this?

(i have implement relevent methods to get data from firebase and assign those data to v_list in state. i haven't include those methods here. they are working fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your version of `react-native-elements`.

This error is usually caused by importing something that doesn't exist.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

In version `1+` the component `List` was deprecated. You can read more about what has been deprecated and what hasn't by checking the dependency's [blog](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/blog/#list). Also several props for `ListItem` were also deprecated, you can see which ones [here](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/blog/#listitem).

The fact that you are using `List` and `roundAvatar` suggests that you may be trying to use the components from version `0.19.1` but with version `1+` installed.

Comment: yeah. my react-native-element version is 1.1.0. i removed those components. thank you very much sir.

Comment: It always pays to make sure that the version you are using matches the documentation that you are using. It is easy to get out of sync and it causes no end of headaches. I'm glad your issue is now resolved.